# Try Catch Mulithread C#

Tags: windows, forms, try-catch

I have a program that have 2 threads running at the same time. Every method is surrounded with a try and catch. If one of the threads creates an exception will it stop the other thread from working as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It will only stop the current thread. The other thread will continue working.

Exceptions are being stored in the stack of each thread.

You can pass exception information between threads using asynchronous delegates:

[Catching an exception thrown in an asynchronous callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748645/catching-an-exception-thrown-in-an-asynchronous-callback)