# Strange issue when .NET InsertMediaUpload to Upload CSV to BigQuery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm using .NET Client API: IUploadProgress progress = insertMediaUpload.Upload() to upload a csv to BigQuery. Basically what I do is:
1. submit a uploading job, 
2. get the job status (pending, running, done..)
3. if there are any errors given by BigQuery, then print them and throw exceptions for further handling.

The code below is not doing exactly what I want and I hope someone can help me to improve it.

Specifically, several strange code behavior happened:
1. even running the same code on the same CSV which was made intentionally for fail, BQ error messages parsed out in UploadOnResponseReceived() would be printed out in some calls but not in others. why?
2.   IUploadProgress value seems to be relevant to UploadOnResponseReceived() behavior: if I do nothing in UploadOnResponseReceived, then progress.status will always be 'Completed', if UploadOnResponseReceived throws an exception, then progress.status will be failed. 
3. when progress.status failed, there's no way to get the exception throwed from UploadOnResponseReceived. I actually do need to get the exception, how should I do?

```
 public bool ExecuteUploadJobToTable(string dataset, string tableId, string filePath, TableSchema schema, string createDisposition, char delimiter)
    {

        TableReference destTable = new TableReference { ProjectId = _account.ProjectId, DatasetId = dataset, TableId = tableId };

        JobConfigurationLoad configLoad = new JobConfigurationLoad 
        {
            Schema = schema,
            DestinationTable = destTable,
            Encoding = "ISO-8859-1",
            CreateDisposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            WriteDisposition = createDisposition,
            FieldDelimiter = delimiter.ToString(),
            AllowJaggedRows = true,
            SourceFormat = "CSV"
        };

        JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration {Load = configLoad};

        Job job = new Job {Configuration = config};

        //set job reference (mainly job id)
        JobReference jobRef = new JobReference
        {
            JobId = GenerateJobID("Upload"),
            ProjectId = _account.ProjectId
        };
        job.JobReference = jobRef;

        bool isSuccess = true;
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            JobsResource.InsertMediaUpload insertMediaUpload = new JobsResource.InsertMediaUpload(BigQueryService, job, job.JobReference.ProjectId, stream: fileStream, contentType: "application/octet-stream");
            insertMediaUpload.ProgressChanged += UploadOnProgressChanged;
            insertMediaUpload.ResponseReceived += UploadOnResponseReceived;

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("start {0}",jobRef.JobId));
            IUploadProgress progress = insertMediaUpload.Upload();
            if (progress.Status.ToString().Contains("Fail"))
            {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(isSuccess);
        return isSuccess;
    }

    private void UploadOnProgressChanged(IUploadProgress process)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(process.Status + " " + process.BytesSent);
    }

    //thowring an exception will make IUploadProgress "Failed", otherwise, IUploadProgress will be "Completed"
    private void UploadOnResponseReceived(Job job)
    {
        try
        {
            job = PollUntilJobDone(job.JobReference, 5);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexcepted unretryable exception happens when poll job status");
            throw new BigQueryException("Unexcepted unretryable exception happens when poll job status",e);
        }

        StringBuilder errorMessageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        ErrorProto fatalError = job.Status.ErrorResult;
        IList<ErrorProto> errors = job.Status.Errors;
        if (fatalError != null)
        {
            errorMessageBuilder.AppendLine("Job failed while writing to Bigquery. " + fatalError.Reason + ": " + fatalError.Message +
                      " at " + fatalError.Location);
        }
        if (errors != null)
        {
            foreach (ErrorProto error in errors)
            {
                errorMessageBuilder.AppendLine("Error: [REASON] " + error.Reason + " [MESSAGE] " + error.Message +
                                               " [LOCATION] " + error.Location);
            }

        }
        if (errorMessageBuilder.Length>0)//fatalError != null || errors != null  
        {
            Console.WriteLine(errorMessageBuilder.ToString());
            throw new BigQueryException(errorMessageBuilder.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("upload should be successful");
    }

    private Job PollUntilJobDone(JobReference jobReference, int pauseSeconds)
    {
        int backoff = 1000;//backoff starts from 1 sec + random

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var pollJob = BigQueryService.Jobs.Get(jobReference.ProjectId, jobReference.JobId).Execute();
                Console.WriteLine(jobReference.JobId + ": " + pollJob.Status.State);
                if (pollJob.Status.State.Equals("DONE"))
                {
                    return pollJob;
                }
                // Pause execution for pauseSeconds before polling job status again,
                // to reduce unnecessary calls to the BigQuery API and lower overall
                // application bandwidth.
                Thread.Sleep(pauseSeconds * 1000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                BigQueryException exception = new BigQueryException(e.Message,e);
                if (exception.IsTemporary)
                {
                    int sleep = backoff + Random.Next(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("pollUntilJobDone job execute failed. Sleeping {0} ms before retry", sleep);
                    Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            backoff *= 2;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample job ids where you observed different error responses for the same input files? Other than the rare network connection error, the same input should result in the same output. Different behavior is worth investigating. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your "how do I catch the exception" question, it seems like the callbacks occur asynchronously on another thread. If you throw an exception, it's going to be caught by whatever framework is calling the callback.

Searching around for similar questions I found these answers that might help you: [Catching an exception thrown in an asynchronous callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748645/catching-an-exception-thrown-in-an-asynchronous-callback), and this one shows how to update UI in another thread from the upload progress received in the background thread: [Tracking upload progress of WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728622/tracking-upload-progress-of-webclient)